# Possible roles of an Alert button in Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, alert

What are the possible values for the `role` property of a button on an Alert in the Ionic framework (v5)?

The documentations just mentions `cancel`: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#buttons

> Optionally, a `role`  property can be added to a button, such as `cancel`.

Example:

```
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Okay',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Confirm Okay');
          }
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think role only have 1 property i.e `'cancel'`.

As mentioned in Documentation:

> "Optionally, a role property can be added to a button, such as cancel.
> If a cancel role is on one of the buttons, then if the alert is
> dismissed by tapping the backdrop, then it will fire the handler from
> the button with a cancel role."

So you can handle it when user dismiss it by clicking on backdrop. it means if you want to do something on cancellation but user dismiss alert by click outside(backdrop) you can still handle it.

Comment: I know about "cancel" and how it works ... I was wondering if there are any other roles because they write "such as". But probably not (as of now).

Comment: this is what I found from source of alert buttons: `@param role The role of the element that is dismissing the alert.
   * This can be useful in a button handler for determining which button was
   * clicked to dismiss the alert.
   * Some examples include: ``"cancel"`, `"destructive"`, "selected"`, and `"backdrop"`.`
Check here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/core/src/components/alert/alert.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the `alert-interface.ts`, the predefined roles are 'cancel' and 'destructive', but also it accepts any string you may want to use as roles.

```
export interface AlertButton {
  text: string;
  role?: 'cancel' | 'destructive' | string;
  cssClass?: string | string[];
  id?: string;
  handler?: (value: any) => boolean | void | {
    [key: string]: any;
  };
}
```